# Unable to set default value on AngularJS select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and trying to set a default value on a select box. I have a list of objects that I want to list in a select box. This works fine, and any binding to the model associated with the select box works fine. However, as soon as I set a default value, all of my bindings doesn't want to update for some reason.

Controller:

```
    app.controller('ctrl', [ '$scope', function ctrl($scope){

        api.get('dealerships', function(err, dealerships){
            $scope.dealerships = dealerships;
            $scope.$apply();
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
    <select ng-model="dealership" ng-options="d.name for d in dealerships"></select>

    <span class="dealership-name">{{dealership.name}}</span>
```

This works just fine, I can toggle between dealerships and the **dealership.name** binding gets updated just fine. However, as soon as I set a default value like this:

```
    app.controller('ctrl', [ '$scope', function ctrl($scope){

        api.get('dealerships', function(err, dealerships){
            $scope.dealerships = dealerships;
            $scope.dealership = $scope.dealerships[0];
            $scope.$apply();
        });

    });
```

All of my binding with **dealership** stays the same, they stay to dealerships[0].

As it might be easier to understand with an image:
[image: problem]

Anyone has any clues? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code in Fiddle. Here is template: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/552/

Comment: Do you really need that `$scope.apply()` ? Or is your `get` not starting a digest cycle?

Comment: Sound like `api.get` doesnt refer to controller

Comment: api.get is not an AngularJS module or anything. It's a custom built SDK to access a custom built API.

Comment: For some reason, this works fine in a Fiddle. Let me do some digging around I guess, and update the Fiddle to match as closely to what we have.

Comment: Ffs... I had two ng-controller reference to the same controller, that select box is in the top nav, and the "For Dealership" is in the content. The top nav and the content had ```ng-controller="ctrl"```. That would explain it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had two ng-controller="ctrl" attributes. One on the navigation bar, where my select box was sitting. And one on the main content, where the binding occured.